# access remote network from within docker container

Tags: docker

I have a Docker Host that is connected to a non-default route network. My problem is now that I can't reach this Network from within the Docker Containers on the Docker Host.

```
Primary IP: 189.69.77.21  (default route)
Secondary IP: 192.168.77.21
```

Routing is like the following:

```
[root@mgmt]# route -n
Kernel IP Routentabelle
Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         189.69.77.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp0s31f6
189.69.77.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 enp0s31f6
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.77.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s31f6.4000
```

and IPtables untouched:

```
[root@mgmt]# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:3000

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

I start the Docker Container with the following:

```
docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped -p 127.0.0.1:3000:3000/tcp --name mongoclient -e MONGOCLIENT_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL=mongodb://192.168.77.21:27017,192.168.77.40:27017,192.168.77.41:27017/graylog?replicaSet=ars0 -e ROOT_URL=http://192.168.77.21/nosqlclient mongoclient/mongoclient
```

I can reach the container (via NGINX Proxy) over Network but the container itself can only ping/reach the Docker Host IP and not others.

```
node@1c5cf0e8d14c:/opt/meteor/dist/bundle$ ping 192.168.77.21
PING 192.168.77.21 (192.168.77.21) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.77.21: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.078 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.77.21: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.080 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.77.21: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.079 ms
^C
--- 192.168.77.21 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.078/0.079/0.080/0.000 ms

node@1c5cf0e8d14c:/opt/meteor/dist/bundle$ ping 192.168.77.40
PING 192.168.77.40 (192.168.77.40) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.77.40 ping statistics ---
240 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 239000ms
```

So my question is, how can I make the Docker Container reach the hosts on the Network? My goal is to have a running [mongoclient](https://www.nosqlclient.com/) via Docker that can be used to manage the MongoDB ReplicaSet that is in that additional private Network.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the network host in the container. So the container is use the host network and you can access the container and host network.

Here is the documentation:

https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

BR
Carlos

Comment: Looking at the linked page I can see:
> If you use the host network mode for a container, that container’s network stack is not isolated from the Docker host (the container shares the host’s networking namespace), and the container does not get its own IP-address allocated. For instance, if you run a container which binds to port 80 and you use host networking, the container’s application is available on port 80 on the host’s IP address.

What makes me not wanting this. Because it would open the Container to the World